# i want to be any date format into this date format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I want to create a function that converts all date formats into single date format (yyyy-mm-dd).

```
function taskDate(dt){
    console.log(dt)
}
var dt = new Date("15-10-2022")
var d = dt.getDate();
var m = dt.getMonth() + 1;
var y = dt.getFullYear();
var dateString =  y + '-' + (m <= 9 ? '0' + m : m) + "-" + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d);
taskDate(dateString)
```

the problem occurred in dd-mm-yyyy format its converts day into month automatically and when the day is more than 12 its returns, Nan.

[image]

Comment: Javascript has some limitations in `Date()`. If you want to support all possible date formats, Consider using libraries such as https://date-fns.org/ instead of writing your own code.

Comment: dayjs is also a good option for handling date formats:https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs

Comment: @BadPiggie  yeah, but why its converts day into months when its more than 12

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I will console the y, d, and m but its output is Nan when the day is more than 12

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález no there is nothing like rude it just shows Nan

Comment: Note also that YYYY-MM-DD is parsed as UTC, not local, so may appear to return the wrong date for hosts with a negative offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a date to the yyyy-MM-dd format, the Swedish locale can be used.

By the way, your date is actually invalid. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

```js
var dt = new Date(2022, 9, 15); // the 2nd arg is monthIndex (starts from 0)
var str = dt.toLocaleString('sv-SE'); // Swedish locale
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You input date string is invalid to `Date`.

```js
var dt = new Date('15-10-2022');
console.log(dt)
```

You can swap `day of month` and `month` and it will work as expected as:

```js
var dt = new Date('10-15-2022');
console.log(dt);
```

**`FINAL CODE`**

```js
function taskDate(dt) {
    console.log(dt);
}
var dt = new Date('10-15-2022');
var d = dt.getDate();
var m = dt.getMonth() + 1;
var y = dt.getFullYear();
var dateString =
    y + '-' + (m <= 9 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d);
taskDate(dateString);
```

To convert from `dd-mm-yyyy` to `mm-dd-yyyy` as:

```js
const date = '15-10-2022';
const [dd, mm, yy] = date.split('-');
const newDate = [mm, dd, yy].join('-');
console.log(newDate);
```

Comment: what if the user passes the date in dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: then you can convert it to `mm-dd-yyyy`

Comment: @VikashChoudhary I've added that code in my answer